# How to Get Owin context from token (from Query string)

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api, owin, bearer-token, hangfire

Can I initialize an Owin context from a token in Querystring?

I use Owin with bearer token, but when I try to authorize the access to HangFire I get null from User (Identity).

But I have the token in querystring. Can I use it to get the user? or initialize the context?

Code:

```cs
public class HFAuthorizationFilter : Hangfire.Dashboard.IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment)
    {
        var context = new OwinContext(owinEnvironment);


        if (context.Authentication.User == null)//always null!?
            return false;

        return context.Authentication.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "SuperAdmin")
            || context.Authentication.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible to deserialize the token to an Identity, but I don't think, that it's a good practice, to do that in code. What OWIN middleware are you using for authentication? I believe, that there is no middleware by Microsoft, which utilizes the query string for passing tokens....

Comment: @FPar I use bearer token, and don't know how to pass it to hangfire!

Comment: Are you using that OWIN Middleware provided by Microsoft? That is not clear for me. It doesn't support the query string by default for authentication, but have a look here, how to do that: http://leastprivilege.com/2013/10/31/retrieving-bearer-tokens-from-alternative-locations-in-katanaowin/